# Using readonly on a reactive object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

Suppose you have a `reactive` object that you want to export as `readonly` as explained [here](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#readonly).

```js
import { reactive, readonly } from '@vue/composition-api'

const graph = reactive({
  profile: {
    givenName: '',
    surName: '',
  }
})

return {
   profile: () => readonly(graph.profile)
}
```

The method `readonly()` does not seem to be a part of the VueCompositionAPI:

> "export 'readonly' was not found in '@vue/composition-api'

I know that when using `ref` you can simply use a `computed` property

```js
return {
   profile: computed(() => graph.profile)
}
```

But for a `reactive` object, where we don't want to use the `.value` every time, this doesn't seem possible. Am I missing something super obvious here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `reactive` doesn't belong to composition api plugin because of the limitation of the language (JS). Vue 3.0 will solve that via proxies.

The second question, I'll give you a direct answer: **no**, you can't return a reactive value as a read-only property without using a computed property. That's not possible if you don't use the proxies implementation (Vue 3.0+).

If you ask me, I'd go with defining chunks of `computed` vars based on your `reactive` state.

```js
const graph = reactive({
  profile: {
    givenName: '',
    surName: '',
  }
})

return {
  profile: computed(() => graph.profile),
  another: computed(() => graph.another)
}
```

You'd have to use `.value` but at least your return will be clearer and you'll allow object destructuring without tearing down reactivity. If we get creative with the last approach, you can even create your own helper:

```js
function readonlyState(state) {
  const computeds = {}

  for (let key in state) {
    computeds[key] = computed(() => state[key])
  }

  return computeds
}
```

And use it:

```js
const graph = reactive({
  profile: {
    givenName: '',
    surName: '',
  }
})

return readonlyState(state) // { profile }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for . Thank you very much :)